# want to distribute amount from a table in multiple row of different table in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as below

```
Table 1 :                 Table 2:
id item_id tbl_id amount       id tbl_id amount
1     1     1       50           1    1     60
2     3     1       40           2    2     30
3     2     1       20
4     1     2       50
```

I want to distribute tbl2 amount i.e.60 to table 1 rows based on common column tbl_id. the query should give me result as below :

```
tbl1.id tbl1.item_id tbl1.tbl_id tbl1.amount tbl2.amount
   1        1            1          50            50
   2        3            1          40            10
   3        2            1          20             0
   4        1            2          50            30
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the 50 + 20 come from?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumulative sums:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when running_amount < t2.amount
             then t1.amount
             when running_amount - t1.amount < t2.amount
             then t2.amount - t1.amount
             else 0
        end) as table2_amount
from (select t1.*,
             sum(t1.amount) over (partition by t1.tbl_id order by t1.id) as running_amount
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id= t1.tbl_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff for your answer but I made mistake in posting content.

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Linoff : Thanks your answer worked as base for my question.
and below is the query to get output as mentioned.

```
 select t1.*,
   (case when running_amount < t2.amount
         then t1.amount
         when (t2.amount - (running_amount - t1.amount))- t1.amount>=0
         then t1.amount
         when (t2.amount - (running_amount - t1.amount))>0
         then (t2.amount - (running_amount - t1.amount))
         else 0
    end) as table2_amount
from 
(select t1.*,sum(t1.amount) over (partition by t1.tbl_id order by t1.id) as running_amount
from tbl_1 t1) t1 
join
(select tbl_id, sum(amount) as amount from tbl_2 group by tbl_id) t2 on t2.tbl_id= t1.tbl_id
```